# How to speed up xyz Interpolation with interp of big data sets in r

Tags: r, interpolation, large-data

I have a big xyz dataset with irregular points and want to make a regular grid of 1 m resolution for 1km². I am using the the interpolation interp from akima. It works fine with a small dataset, but takes forever for the whole data set (3 columns and over 1 million rows).

Here is an example with less values. My dataset is randomly generated but similar.

It needs about 40 s to run it.

Is there any way to speed this up?

the desired values are commented.

```
x = sort(runif(100000, 300000,301000))# actually I want 1 000 000 and more values
y = runif(100000, 5661000,5662000) # actually I want 1 000 000 and more values
z = runif(100000,50,100)# actually I want 1 000 000 and more values
df = data.frame(x, y, z) 

xmin <- 300200 -100 # 310000
xmax <- 300800 +100 # 311000
ymin <- 5661200 -100 # 5661000
ymax <- 5661800 +100 # 5662000
gridint <- 100 # actually I want 1 000 values

library(akima)

system.time(fld<- with(df, interp(x = x, y = y, z = z, linear = T, extrap = F,duplicate= "mean",
                            xo=seq(xmin, xmax, length=gridint), 
                              yo=seq(ymin, ymax, length=gridint))))  

contour(fld)   # Left graph (most basic graphic output)

fld2 <- as.data.frame(interp2xyz(fld))
```

Comment: Why is it a problem that it takes 40 s? Do you have to run it a million times?